# TTL Behavior - HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We have lot of data in a HBase table. Am new to this NoSQL world. We are looking to keep data only for fixed time. Should we write a separate clean up script or can we rely on TTL configuration?

I went through the docs available but am not understanding the exact behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HBase [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/book/ttl.html) clearly says that data older than TTL will be automatically deleted by HBase.

Comment: eah.. I wrote a program and was able to see the behavior myself. Is there a way I can induce major compatcion in the code?

Comment: No, it's very unclear. The original words are "ColumnFamilies can set a TTL length in seconds, and HBase will automatically delete rows once the expiration time is reached. This applies to all versions of a row - even the current one. " The 2nd sentence is very vague. What does he mean by "applies to all versions"? Like if the oldest value reaches the TTL, the newest will be deleted, too? I personally tested it by setting up the TTL to 60 seconds and inserting 6 values per 10 senconds, and found it is not the case. HBase deleted these 6 values one by one every 10 second.

Comment: I have tested it in production environment,on 3 different table. passing the TTL from FOREVER to 4 YEARS using :

alter 'xxxxx:yyyyyyyy', {NAME=>'z', TTL => '126144000'}


i CONFIRM that the data was purged, passing from 4100 giga to 3800 giga in 2 hours, only with automatic minor compact.

i did not use major compact

Answer (score 2):

Remember that data is never deleted by HBase until it does a compaction -- where it rewrites all of its data files. Once the data passes it TTL it will be invisible until a major compaction happens.

Comment: this is exactly internal hbase working mechanism. also, if you put a delete with ts in the future, you won't be able to create that record until that future time is reached, or major compaction happens, whoever comes first.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves the way it says, i.e all the values in a row whose timestamps are older than the
configured TTL will be deleted at the next major compaction. It is an attribute of the column family. If you want the TTL to apply to the entire table, simply set it to the same value
for each column family in the table. This way you will get rid of the data once you are done with it.